# Average and max values given a definition

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, average, maxima-minima

suppose $$|r - \sqrt n| < M < 9(\sqrt n)$$
with M, r ∈ N

prove that:

max of $|r^2 - n|$ is at most $(M-1)^2 + 2*M* ceil\sqrt n$ and

average of $|r^2 - n|$ is $M * (floor(\sqrt n) + ceil(\sqrt n))/2$

I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that $(r+\sqrt n)(r - \sqrt n) = r^2- n$ but I'm not sure what to do with this information.